# Check whether React.Suspense is ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

I'm using the Intersection Observer API in React to add some animations. I am adding as Intersection Entries some elements.

The problem is that I have the app in multiple languages, and due to the implementation that the tool I am using to translate has, I need to wrap all my components into React.Suspense to wait for languages to load.

When `useEffect` queries for the elements, they aren't still in the DOM, and therefore they are not assigned as entries.

This is my custom hook:

> hooks/useObserver.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function useObserver(config = {}) {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

  const observer = useRef(
    new IntersectionObserver(observedEntries => {
      setEntries(observedEntries);
    }, config)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current: currentObserver } = observer;

    currentObserver.disconnect();

    if (elements.length > 0) {
      elements.forEach(el => currentObserver.observe(el));
    }
    return () => {
      if (currentObserver) {
        currentObserver.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, [elements]);

  return { observer: observer.current, setElements, entries };
}
```

and this is my main component:

> App.jsx

```js
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Hero from "./components/Hero";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Loader } from "./components/shared/Loader";
import { useObserver } from "./hooks/useObserver";
import { useEffect, Suspense } from "react";

function App() {
  const { entries, setElements } = useObserver({});

  useEffect(() => {
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section.animated-section");
      setElements(sections);
    };
  }, [setElements]);

  useEffect(() => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      entry.target.classList.toggle("section-visible", entry.isIntersecting);
    });
  }, [entries]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Header />
      <Hero />
      <Footer />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to set a timeout to wait some seconds and then add the elements as entries, and it works correctly:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const observeElements = () => {
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section.animated-section");

      setElements(sections);
    };

    const observeElementsTimeout = setTimeout(observeElements, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(observeElementsTimeout)
  }, [setElements]);
```

I want to know if:

- There is a way to know when React.Suspense is ready
- There is a better approach to solve my problem

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try useEffect's return function with empty dependencies array, which will be executed before Loader component unmount (this could be the right moment to ensure that React.Suspense is ready):

```
function Loader({ onUnmount }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      onUnmount();
    };
  }, []);

  return <LoaderComponent />;
}

function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  // App component logic here

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader onUnmount={() => setIsReady(true)} />}>
      <HeavyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply encapsulate this hierarchy into its own component and call the useObserver behaviour? That should ensure that when the component is rendered, all of the nodes are available.

```js
const Page = () => {

  const { entries, setElements } = useObserver({});

  useEffect(() => {
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section.animated-section");
      setElements(sections);
    };
  }, [setElements]);

  useEffect(() => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      entry.target.classList.toggle("section-visible", entry.isIntersecting);
    });
  }, [entries]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Hero />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

and App can simply be

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <Page />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

This approach ensures that you are still using component composability and maintaining single responsibility per component too.